# Did I break the console with my range function?

Tags: javascript, loops, range

```js
range = (arg1, arg2, arg3) => {
    let arr = [];
    let min = Math.min(arg1, arg2);
    if (arg3 != undefined) {
        // let i = min;
        while (min <= Math.max(arg1, arg2)) {
            min += arg3;
            arr.push(min);
        }
    } else {
        for (let i = min; i <= Math.max(arg1, arg2); i++) {
            arr.push(i);
        }
    } 
    return arr;
}

console.log(range(1, 10));
// → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
console.log(range(5, 2, -1));
// → [5, 4, 3, 2]
// console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));
// → 55


// sum = (arr) => {
//     let sum = 0;
//     for (let numbs of arr) {
//         sum += numbs;
//     }
//     return sum;
// }

// console.log(sum(range(1,10)));
// // 55
```

I really can't see where I went wrong with this. What's wrong here exactly??

And what's up with the cryptic error messages:

```
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Fatal JavaScript invalid size error 169220804
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0000009A0CAFE560
 1: 00007FF7D71E815F v8::internal::CodeObjectRegistry::~CodeObjectRegistry+114079
 2: 00007FF7D710343F std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<+65023
 3: 00007FF7D7DE2EE2 V8_Fatal+162
 4: 00007FF7D7966D35 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArray+101
 5: 00007FF7D78271B2 v8::debug::Script::GetIsolate+16706
 6: 00007FF7D769A9A1 v8::internal::CompilationCache::IsEnabledScriptAndEval+26913
 7: 00007FF7D7B39701 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+494417
 8: 00000239C87C9080
```

Please someone help me, I feel like I am blind, I can't begin to comprehend whether there's even any errors in this function.

Comment: For starters `console.log(min)` within your loop and you will realize that your logic is off, you just endlessly decrement "forever" until your container crashes. You start at 2 (which is wrong) and then subtract 1 and never stop because all values will be lower than any two input values you start with.

Comment: It's an OOM (out of memory) error. You're endlessly adding elements to an array. You didn't "break" the console, you just killed the JavaScript process.

Comment: @luk2302 oh shoot, that happens when arg3 < 0 right?

Comment: I think, if arg3 is positive it should be `for (let i = min; i <= max; i += arg3)`, if arg3 is negative `for (let i = max; i >= min; i += arg3)`